# PHP(PHP4) Update data with looping got "500 Internal Server Error" on CentOS but not in windows (XAMPP)

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, server

I have about 600 record from output query.
Then I make a update script with looping **foreach**

On windows with xampp 1.7.3 (PHP5 and MySQL5) that's run normally and fast. And sucessfully updated.

But when i upload to my host (CentOS server) i see the proccess update data is get long, and then i got 500 Internal Server Error. When the proccess running, i refresh table database, the update data is long time each row. So only about 20 record can updated, and then got 500 internal server error.

For information, on my host application server (PHP4) and database server (MySQL4) is different server.

Proccess update data with looping array :

`foreach($kode as $id => $kdid) {
  $page->adodb->StartTrans();
  $qw->sqlExecute($sql['update_data'],array($tglmasuk[$id],$no_urutan[$id],$kode[$id]), false);
  $page->adodb->CompleteTrans();
}`

file sql :

`$sql['update_data'] = "UPDATE history
 SET
   tgl_masuk = '%s',
   no_urutan = '%s'
 WHERE id_history = '%s'"`

error log :

> [Mon Mar 16 08:47:19 2015] [warn] [client 192.168.1.122] Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /var/www/cgi-bin/php, referer: http://myurlproccessubmit
>
> [Mon Mar 16 08:47:19 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.122] Premature end of script headers: php, referer: http://myurlproccessubmit

Can someone help me for solve the problem??

Comment: Posting your relevant code may assist you in getting some help.

Comment: i has update my question with some script process @PaulGriffin

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the script not completing within the maximum allowed execution time.

You can try to increase the max execution time with the following command at the beginning of your script:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',120);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

max_execution_time can also be set in the .htaccess file with:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_execution_time 120
</IfModule>
```

You may also ask the hosting company for help.

Comment: the hosting is own host :)
and for max_execution_time i has set on first line in script :
    ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
report is keep 500 internal server error @user2182349